# Kafka with cloudera TLS failures

Tags: security, ssl, apache-kafka, consumer

I have cloudera manager with kafka. Kafka configured to work with TLS, on application side i have producer and consumers that also has all parameters required for establish secure connection.

However while my application starts, kafka consumers starting poll messages and failing, don't sure it is failing because of handshake exception, this is the error

```
Consumer-0-C-1, fatal error: 80: problem unwrapping net record
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
AsyncActionTopicContainer-0-C-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
AsyncActionTopicContainer-0-C-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
AsyncActionTopicContainer-0-C-1, called closeOutbound()
AsyncActionTopicContainer-0-C-1, closeOutboundInternal()
AsyncActionTopicContainer-0-C-1, called closeInbound()
AsyncActionTopicContainer-0-C-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
```

What can be a problem?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with self signed certificate? Have you check your certificate with openssl?

Comment: No. I will enhance my question. 
Actually TLS is working fine, but when I want explicitly define cipher suites, which is part of parameters for my application producer and consumer, I am starting to receive above exception.

Comment: Maybe you're crossing a network with some firewall or proxy? Or you have something that interacts with your network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem was that on consumer/provider side (app) I used cipher suite that doesn't supported. That is why received above mentioned exception.